# INotifyPropertyChanged chaining through nested objects and updating totals

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have the following structure of classes:

```
class Building : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public double TotalArea 
    {
        get { return _totalarea; }
    }
    private double _totalarea;
    public List<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
}

class Floor: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public double TotalArea 
    {
        get { return _totalarea; }
    }
    private double _totalarea;
    public List<Room> Rooms{ get; set; }
}

class Room: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public double Area 
    {
        get { return _area; }
        set 
        {
            _area = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Area");
        }
    }
    private double _area;
}
```

I want to maintain notification chain through the classes so that if Room.Area is changed, new Room added to or existing deleted from Floor.Rooms, the Floor.TotalArea would update and instantly also Building.TotalArea would update.

Besides this the UI (WPF) binds to these properties and must get notified as well of changes in TotalArea and Area properties of these classes.

My application has grown into a large one and adding event handlers to monitor child class property changes is starting to become messy. I am looking a clean and elegant solution to chain property notifications and update totals on parent class without sacrificing the performance too much.

How to chain the property notifications to update totals in this kind of nested objects?

Comment: this cannot be answered in a few sentences - yes you can do it by building combinators and functors to work with the events in the background. And it has already been done - for example in [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) and I would recommend you have a look at some of those frameworks first.

Comment: A third-party library might be the way to go. If not, then you will have to be more specific about what you're doing now and what specifically you don't like/want about that. There's nothing in the code example you've provided so far that shows _any_ sort of dependencies between your various objects, in terms of responding to change notification events. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice as to what constitutes a _good_ code example.